# jQuery easyui dialog onload event fired twice after resized

Tags: jquery-easyui

I override the onLoad method of Dialog,like this:

```
$('#billInfoDlg').dialog({
        onLoad: function () {
              console.log("fire onload event");
        } 
})
```

if I resize the window when the dialog is opened,then,I close but not destroy the dialog.When I reopen the dialog ,the onLoad event were fired twice!